# RuntimeException: Unable to start activity for retrofit in main activity in android

Tags: android, retrofit2

hi i'm a bit new to android studio
i'm coding with java and i need help, the thing is that when i put my retrofit codes to Call in mainactivity it won't response;here's my code in Mainactivity how ever I put my codes it gives me these errors in build.
oh and I have already googled it but couldn't find cananyone help please,thanks.
 Mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ParentActivity {
Call<HealthServices>call;
final String TAG="here";
ArrayList<HealthServices> healthServices;

Button btn_signin, btn_signup;
EditText enter_eamil, enter_pass;
public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if(!getUserHelper().hasUser()){
       openActivity(Activity_Register.class, true);
    } else {
        openActivity(HomeActivity.class, true);
    }

    // test kon

    init();

    login();
    register();

    HealthServices healthServices=APIUtils.getHealthServices();
    Call<HList>call=healthServices.getInfoo("JSON","");
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+"TEST");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<HList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<HList> call, Response<HList> response) {
            HList hList=response.body();



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<HList> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG+" ERROR", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
      }
         private void register() {
         btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

     private void login() {
     btn_signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            String mainPass = enter_pass.getText().toString().trim();
            String mainMail = enter_eamil.getText().toString().trim();

            if (isValidInput(mainMail, mainPass)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
    });
}

     private void init() {
    btn_signin = findViewById(R.id.main_btn_signin);
    btn_signup = findViewById(R.id.main_btn_signup);
    enter_eamil = findViewById(R.id.main_et);
    enter_pass = findViewById(R.id.main_pass);
}

private boolean isValidInput(String mail, String pass) {

    //get data of memory
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String emails = prefs.getString("EMAIL", "");
    String pass1 = prefs.getString("PASS", "");

    if (isEmpty(mail)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (isEmpty(pass)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!mail.equals(emails)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!pass.equals(pass1)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    }

    }
```

and heres's my errors comes up in build:

```
      02/22 22:20:16: Launching 'app' on Pixel 2 API 29.
    $ adb shell am start -n "com.example.najmidpi/com.example.najmidpi.activity.MainActivity" -a 
    android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
    Waiting for process to come online...
    Connected to process 30993 on device 'Pixel_2_API_29 [emulator-5554]'.
    Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the 
    "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
    D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
    W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:114): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" 
    dev="tmpfs" ino=849 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 
    tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
    W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission 
    denied)
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
    D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
    W/xample.najmidp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;- 
    >computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, 
    allowed)
    W/xample.najmidp: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;- 
   >makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.najmidpi, PID: 30993
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.example.najmidpi/com.example.najmidpi.activity.MainActivity}: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://teslam.ir/json%20files
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: baseUrl must end in /: http://teslam.ir/json%20files
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:527)
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:470)
    at com.example.najmidpi.retrofit.remote.RetroClient.getClient(RetroClient.java:18)
    at com.example.najmidpi.retrofit.remote.APIUtils.getHealthServices(APIUtils.java:12)
    at com.example.najmidpi.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
         Process 30993 terminated.
```

and the Logcat is clear.
what should I do?Can someone tell plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message looks quite clear to me

> http://teslam.ir/json%20files

Basically you have to add a `/`
as so:

> http://teslam.ir/json%20files/

the place should be where you have the `Call` or `Observe` interface, is called an endpoint